# Access the content of <ng-template>

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive

Let us say that we have a child component that takes a template as an input :
In child.html:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet=“formTemplate”></ng-container>
```

In child.ts:

```
    @Component({
     selector: ‘child’,
     templateUrl: ‘./child.html’
    })
    export class ChildComponent {
     @Input() formTemplate: TemplateRef<HTMLElement>;
    }
```

In the parent component.html:

```
<child [formTemplate] = “tmpl”></child>
<ng-template #tmpl>
    //some reactive form will be passed here
</ng-template>
```

In parent.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: ‘parent’,
    templateUrl: ‘./parent.html’
})
export class ParentComponent {
}
```

The form is displayed correctly inside the child component.
Is there any way to access the form inside the child component ?
The child needs to access the form to perform some logic when the form is invalid for example.

Comment: I would add another Input too the child component which references the form from the parent.